# How to refactor helper methods in RSpec files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the `rspec-rails 2`gem. I would like to refactor the following code (I have intentionally omitted some code and I have given meaningful names in order to highlight the structure):

```
describe "D1" do
  # Helper method
  def D1_Method_1
    ...
  end

  context "C1" do
    # Helper methods
    def D1_C1_Method_1
      session.should be_nil # Note: I am using the RoR 'session' hash
      D1_Method_1           # Note: I am calling the 'D1_Method_1' helper method
      ...
    end

    def D1_C1_Method_2
      ...
    end


    it "I1" do
      D1_Method_1
      ...
    end

    it "I2" do
      ...
      D1_C1_Method_1
      D1_C1_Method_2
    end
  end

  context "C2" do
    # Helper methods
    def D1_C2_Method_1
      ...
    end

    def D1_C2_Method_2
      ...
    end


    it "I1" do
      D1_Method_1
      ...
    end

    it "I2" do
      ...
      D1_C2_Method_1
      D1_C2_Method_2
    end
  end
end
```

**What can\should I make in order to refactor the above code?**

*P.S.:* I have tried to extract *helper methods* in an external module (named `Sample`) but, for example relating to the `D1_C1_Method_1` method (that contains the RoR `session`), I get the following error when I run the spec file:

```
Failure/Error: session.should be_nil
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `session' for Sample:Module
```

Comment: I was having the same problem; This helped me out:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to include the helpers as an external module?

```
require 'path/to/my_spec_helper'

describe "D1" do
  include MySpecHelper
  ...
end
```

And now the helper:

```
# my_spec_helper.rb
module MySpecHelper
  def D1_C1_Method_1
    session.should be_nil
   ...
  end 
end
```

Comment: I have a `spec/support` directory... how should I state the (absolute or relative) path?